# How to filter MS SQL query by child's table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not very familiar with SQL. I have a following database structure: `Application`, which has N count of `ApplicationSteps`, but each `ApplicationStep` is has one `CaseStep` and each `CaseStep` has `StepType`, which is enum for example with a keys 1 and 2.

Please anyone can help me to take all `Applications`, where `Application` don't have `ApplicationStep`, where `CaseStep.Id = 5 AND CaseStep.StepType = 2`.

My DB structure is follow:

```
1. Application
   - Id
   - Many(ApplicationStep)
2. ApplicationStep
   - Id
   - ApplicationId
   - CaseStepId
3. CaseStep
   - Id
   - StepType
   - Many(ApplicationStep)
```

My current sql query:

```
SELECT  
Application.Id, 
Application.CreationDateTime, 
Application.Status, 
[Case].Name AS CaseName

FROM Application 

LEFT JOIN [Case] ON Application.CaseId = [Case].Id

WHERE Application.CaseId = 6 AND 
      Application.Status = 5 

ORDER BY Application.CreationDateTime 
    DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Application a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ApplicationSteps aps JOIN
                       CaseStep cs
                       ON aps.CaseStepId = c.CaseStepId
                  WHERE aps.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId AND
                        cs.CaseStepId = 5 AND cs.StepType = 2
                 )
ORDER BY a.CreationDateTime DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY ;
```